# Handling multiple screen sizes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm teaching myself Swift by porting an old game from SVGA/PC to iOS/MacOS and SpriteKit. A lot of it is just slogging code - move things from text files to defaults, etc.

But one thing I need to think about now is how I'm going to handle different screen sizes. The original was all hard coded to 640x480 (IIRC) and played in an ever-smaller window.

I'd prefer to have both windowed or full screen mode on any device the game hits. Can anyone offer hints/suggestions/examples of how to best handle this? I'm sure this is a common issue and I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Having a windowed mode for mobile games doesn't make much sense (nor do I believe it is supported), so I would recommend sticking to full screen for mobile devices. You can achieve a responsive UI by using Apple's Autolayout framework.

Comment: google is your friend! try "Universal App SpriteKit"

Comment: Unfortunately those are iOS examples, for them "universal" is "all iOS". I can't find anything that has the same assets on both OS's, as well as being able to scale from the smallest iPod to a 30" screen. Google doesn't turn that up either (at least not my google-fu).

Comment: What about this. Talks about having a single project for both mobile device and computer http://www.raywenderlich.com/70837/how-to-port-your-sprite-kit-game-from-ios-to-os-x